# Play Framework, JSON Read combinator with overriden apply method

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am trying to make somethink like that:

```
case class Obj(name: String, list: List[Integer], isPossible: Boolean) {    
  override def apply(name: String, list: List[Integer]): Obj = {
    Obj(name, list, list.exists((x: Integer) => x >= 10 && x <= 100))
  }
}

implicit val objReads: Reads[Obj] = (
(__ \ "name").read[String] and
(__ \ "list").read[List[Integer]]
)(Book.apply _)
```

but it doesn't compile, it returns me a error:

```
Overloaded method value [apply] cannot be applied to  ((String, List[Integer], Boolean) => models.Api.Obj)
```

is it possible to do this, or just i have to have the same amount of fields in case class and in read combinator, and this is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here. First, the `apply` method for a case class is defined within it's companion object, not the case class itself. The second problem is that once you define the `apply` method within the companion object, it's going to cause an ambiguous reference error in `Obj.apply _`. This is because your declaration of `apply` is an overload, and not an override, since the signatures do not match.

One way to solve this would be to remove `isPossible` from the constructor of `Obj`, and instead make it a method or val. You would still be able to access it the same way.

```
case class Obj(name: String, list: List[Int]) {
    val isPossible: Boolean = list.exists((x: Int) => x >= 10 && x <= 100)
}

object Obj {
    implicit val objReads: Reads[Obj] = (
        (__ \ "name").read[String] and
        (__ \ "list").read[List[Int]]
    )(Obj.apply _)
}
```

The only problem this poses is that `isPossible` would no longer be included in JSON writes, which can be fixed like so:

```
implicit val objWrites: Writes[Obj] = (
    (__ \ "name").write[String] and
    (__ \ "list").write[List[Int]] and 
    (__ \ "isPossible").write[Boolean]
)( obj => (obj.name, obj.list, obj.isPossible) )
```

Alternatively, you could rename the overloaded `apply` to something else, and use that for `Reads` instead of `Obj.apply`. However, I think keeping `isPossible` as a `val` is better, because it's calculation would be done on object creation, and not when being passed to the constructor. This would ensure that you could not just call `Obj("test", List(1), true)` with an invalid state for `isPossible`.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. That was a lesson for me ))

Comment: great suggestion with creating a method specifically for reading (fx. json).